# Is it possible for Perl move success with response 0?

Tags: perl, copy

Every function in the perl `File::Copy` module is supposed to return 1 in case of success and 0 in case of failure.
In my case, I have noticed (using whatever logs I had) that `move` returns 0 even when the operation succeeds (because files are actually moved) with value of $! as `No such file or directory`.

Has anyone noticed such issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If move returns 0, trying to rename the file failed, and then either trying to copy it failed or trying to unlink the original file after copying it failed.  I don't see other possibilities, at least in File::Copy version 2.33.

You may want to just try the rename and, if needed, the copy and unlink yourself, if you need better error reporting.

What version of File::Copy are you using?  What version of perl?  What operating system.

Comment: 2.23, 5.16.3, linux. I am not facing this issue all the time. This happens only for a few files. Anyways, I think I am gonna go with copy and unlink manually.

Answer (score 2):

From [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html), on `copy`

> If an error occurs in setting permissions, `cp` will return 0, regardless of whether the file was successfully copied.

While this is for `copy`, the `move` may also copy the file and then delete it (if it can't rename it).

There are yet other possibilities, that involve other processes interfering with the file.